# ADAM connector for Tridion 2013 sp1

Tags: 2013, publishing, ecl

We need to use ADAM as our asset repository with Tridion 2013

what all we need to start with?

1. licenses?
2. certificates?
3. connectors/providers?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what research you have done already. Have you already read the documentation? Information about licenses can be obtained from the relevant sales representatives (but yes, you will need them).

Answer (score 5):

for

- basic information about [connectors](http://goo.gl/c7nXks) ([login required](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))
- [Installation & certificates Information](http://goo.gl/qSUlFG) ([login required](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

you will also find other information related to aDAM from above links.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to sort out is an ADAM license of course, then you should contact your SDL Web sales/account manager for obtaining the license and software for the ADAM Web Service and ADAM ECL Provider. These are custom parts delivered by SDL, allowing you to create a connection between the two systems.

Then from there just follow the documentation as @Raj suggested, you will automatically get to the topic of creating the required certificates and it is explained where to place them.

Comment: we are using Tridion 2013 SP1. Tridion 2013 SP1 has ADAM connector? or we need to code for it?

Comment: @Naresh the ADAM ECL provider was written for 2011, and should work on 2013 and 2013 SP1 yes, but you will hear those details from your SDL Web sales/account manager I'm sure.